# Visibility/accessablity of default android layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to figure out why some layout files in the android open source project are not accessible from android's R file. I know that the only layout resources I can use are http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html.

What I don't know is why that is only a subset of the layouts in the open source project. For example why is activity_chooser_view_list_item not accessible. https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/activity_chooser_view_list_item.xml

Why are only a subset of the layout files in the project available for reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are only a subset of the layout files in the project available for reference?

They are the only ones considered to be part of the SDK. This is not significantly different than classes and methods that are part of the framework, but not part of the SDK, being marked with `@hide`.

Since those layout files are licensed under the Apache License 2.0, you are welcome to copy any of them into your own project for use, subject to those license terms.

Comment: I don't see the @hide annotation anywhere in https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/activity_chooser_view_list_item.xml does that mean the annotation is in the R file its self?

Comment: @HamiltonBaker: Sorry, I meant the `@hide` as an analogy. You will see that in the framework Java code (e.g., methods on `Activity`). I do not the mechanics by which the Android source code indicates which resources are in and not in the SDK.

Comment: They could use hide in the R file after it was generated. https://code.google.com/p/doclava/wiki/JavadocTags#@hide

Comment: @HamiltonBaker: True, but if `R` is generated, manually applying `@hide` on each compile is unrealistic. Either they have a way of generating `R` that takes some other file as input for what should be in the SDK, or they have some way of post-processing the generated `R` to add the `@hide` annotations separately.

Comment: After some further research it looks like everything they want to hide is defined in [symbols.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/6b8a3a52acf1c2722551f1ea1ce47831f87939cd/core/res/res/values/symbols.xml)

Comment: @HamiltonBaker: Interesting. Note that a comment in that file suggests that it too might be generated from other sources. You can never have enough layers of indirection, I guess... :-)